# High input voltage (12 - 160 VDC) reduce to +5 VDC

Tags: dc-dc-converter

How to make simple el.circuit for DC-DC step down converter useing transistor and resistors ?
Is it possible?
Vin = 12 to 160 VDC
Vout = 5 VDC @ 500 mA

Comment: DC/DC step down using resistors and transistors? You mean only resistors and transistors?

Comment: A DCDC without caps or inductors? Good luck with that. I do not think that 'simple' is feasible anyway. The simplest way is possibly an integrated flyback IC with a small-ish transformer and an external power device. If you do not need galvanic insulation you might get away with only a coil, but 12V to 160V is a big range.

Comment: I have asked if possible?

Comment: No, its not possible to build a voltage conversion device with out a place to store energy. Only Capacitors and Inductors can store energy Resistors and Transistors cannot.

Answer (score 3):

What you are asking for can be done, but is unrealistic.  You could use a high voltage transistor and a zener to drop the input voltage to a roughly regulated 8-10 V or so, then a second stage that can be more accurate to get the final 5 V.

However, this will be horribly inefficient.  At 160 V in, the total dissipation will be 77.5 W.  That takes physical size, and won't be cheap.  A switching power supply, even if you have to roll the whole thing yourself, will look trivial in comparison.

Comment: hey now, that could trivially operate submerged in a bucket of mineral oil for a minute or so.  OP didn't say how long he needed his 2.5 watts out.  Of course, OP didn't say a lot of things about his project...surprise, surprise.

Answer (score 1):

Join TI's [Webench](http://www.ti.com/lsds/ti/analog/webench/overview.page?DCMP=sva_web_webdesigncntr_en&HQS=sva-web-webdesigncntr-vanity-lp-en) enter your Vin - Io requirements and enjoy the options.

You have an exceptionally large Vin range of 12 -160 V which makes this a challenging design and seriously lowers the efficiency you can achieve.
However Webench does offer viable designs, but none are what you could call simple.